# What versions of OS X support 'Find My Mac'?

Tags: macos, find-my-mac

I am running a clean install of OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) and can't seem to locate the 'Find my Mac' feature that I have seen on my friend's machine.

What versions of OS X support 'Find My Mac'?

Comment: It should work on your case too. Try to enable it from icloud.com if you are not able to see it. Check this page https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205362

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimum version of OS X that supports *Find My Device* is 10.7.5 (Lion).  See this [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230) page for more details.

The setting for *Find My Mac* can be found under System Preferences > iCloud.  See this [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205362) page for full details

[image]

Comment: this is good new, but I cant seem to find this iCLoud page in my settings. DO I have to set up iCLoud first for it to show up in the Preferences window?

Comment: ok had to go digging for some prefPane file to show the iCloud pane. Now I just have to figure out how to find the 'find my Mac'. You have answered the question, so I voted for your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Find My Mac since 2021 requires at least Catalina (MacOS 10.15) to be running.

If you are running an earlier version of MacOS, there will still be an option to activate Find My in iCloud settings, however the Mac will not show up when viewing your devices in the Find My app or in [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/find/).

The supported OS version for the various iCloud services can be found on [Apple’s website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230). Specifically, for Find My, the requirements are:

[image: Screenshot of the system requirements for Find My]